# Adding other git repositories into Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

This may seem like a newbie question, but what is the "proper" way to link other libraries into an Xcode project?  For example, suppose you're working on an app and want to use a the asi-http-request library or tapku, which are hosted on Github.  I just drop into the terminal, use `git clone` to get a local copy of the repository, but then what?

Is the right thing to just add the path to the `Header Search Paths`?  Or create a folder in Xcode and drag the directory into the project?

I've reviewed a few SO posts on this, but can't quite decide what the best practice is here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred method is to add the include and library directories to my project, with the group hierarchy matching the actual file system hierarchy. That way you don't need to mess about with settings for header paths, library paths, etc, *and* as a bonus you can easily look up stuff in the header files when needed (e.g. via Command-D). As your project grows and you have more third party libraries etc you'll find this method a lot more manageable.

Comment: That's what I do. If you don't want to have loads of files you can also compile the library and link that instead (not hard to do).

Comment: Agree with this method. And actually, if you are working with your project using Git, you could add this kind of libraries as a git submodule.

Comment: OK, but if you need to update the library, won't you need to overwrite / re-copy the file into your project?

Comment: @Neal: you just need to update the library on disk - Xcode will pick up the changes and recompile/relink as necessary - no user intervention needed as far as the project itself is concerned.

Comment: @PaulR: so what you're saying then is: (1) set up a folder in the Xcode project to keep the libraries in, (2) clone a local copy of the repo off of github, then (3) drag the library's folders into the folder created in Xcode and _not_ check the `copy items into destination's group folder` option?  Any missing/incorrect steps here?  Thanks.

Comment: @Neal: yes, but I think it's possibly even simpler than that - I usually create groups in Xcode that map to the normal install directories, e.g. `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/local/lib`, plus relevant subdirectories, then do the `./configure && make && make install` from the local repository. You can then just add the relevant files (headers and libraries) to your project (without copying, as you say).